# Import GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin

Tags: python, gensim

I am working on code using the gensim and having a tough time troubleshooting a ValueError within my code. I finally was able to zip GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz file so I could implement it in my model. I also tried gzip which the results were unsuccessful. The error in the code occurs in the last line. I would like to know what can be done to fix the error. Is there any workarounds? Finally, is there a website that I could reference?

Thank you respectfully for your assistance!

```
import gensim
from keras import backend
from keras.layers import Dense, Input, Lambda, LSTM, TimeDistributed
from keras.layers.merge import concatenate
from keras.layers.embeddings import Embedding
from keras.models import Mode

pretrained_embeddings_path = "GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin"
word2vec = 
gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(pretrained_embeddings_path, 
binary=True)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-23bd96c1d6ab> in <module>()
  1 pretrained_embeddings_path = "GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin"
----> 2 word2vec = 
gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(pretrained_embeddings_path, 
binary=True)

C:\Users\green\Anaconda3\envs\py35\lib\site-
packages\gensim\models\keyedvectors.py in load_word2vec_format(cls, fname, 
fvocab, binary, encoding, unicode_errors, limit, datatype)
244                             word.append(ch)
245                     word = utils.to_unicode(b''.join(word), 
encoding=encoding, errors=unicode_errors)
--> 246                     weights = fromstring(fin.read(binary_len), 
dtype=REAL)
247                     add_word(word, weights)
248             else:

ValueError: string size must be a multiple of element size
```

Comment: I can execute your code without an error. Have you made sure, you have the latest version of gensim? Did you actually zip the vector file (as you wrote in your post) or did you mean "unzip"? Have you tried setting `binary=false` to check if you might have the text file instead of the binary one?

Comment: I used Winzip to zip the file. I also tried binary=false.  I get the same results with latest version of gensim. I am using Python 3.6.

Comment: I suspect your file is corrupt, or not really the un-gzipped binary file. Gensim can read the `.gz` file just fine, so you could use that raw. Try downloading fresh & ensuring the size is as expected. If you still have problems, report the MD5 hash of the file you're trying, to compare against the version others have.

Comment: Thank you .I stumbled upon the wget package and download the bin file that way. I'll give it another try.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Edit: The S3 url has stopped working. You can d[ownload the data from Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/leadbest/googlenewsvectorsnegative300) or use [this Google Drive link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7XkCwpI5KDYNlNUTTlSS21pQmM/edit?resourcekey=0-wjGZdNAUop6WykTtMip30g) (be careful downloading files from Google Drive).

The below commands **no longer work** work.

```
brew install wget

wget -c "https://s3.amazonaws.com/dl4j-distribution/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz"
```

This downloads the GZIP compressed file that you can uncompress using:

```bash
gzip -d GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz
```

You can then use the below command to get **wordVector**.

```
from gensim import models

w = models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(
    '../GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin', binary=True)
```

Comment: I am getting this warning: `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/smart_open/smart_open_lib.py:253: UserWarning: This function is deprecated, use smart_open.open instead. See the migration notes for details: https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/smart_open/blob/master/README.rst#migrating-to-the-new-open-function
  'See the migration notes for details: %s' % _MIGRATION_NOTES_URL
` Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: remember this is a huge file with over a billion words

Comment: This command doesn't work for me. I get:
`ERROR 404: Not Found`. I found this https://github.com/mmihaltz/word2vec-GoogleNews-vectors , but this link may disappear at some point too

Comment: Is there a Java library that reads such .bin files?

Answer (score 21):

try this -

```
import gensim.downloader as api

wv = api.load('word2vec-google-news-300')

vec_king = wv['king']
```

also, visit this link : https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/auto_examples/tutorials/run_word2vec.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-tutorials-run-word2vec-py

Comment: Unfortunately, the model is unable to infer vectors for unfamiliar words. This is one limitation of Word2Vec: if this limitation matters to you, check out the FastText model.

Answer (score 17):

you have to write the complete path.

use this path:

https://s3.amazonaws.com/dl4j-distribution/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: We (Skymind) would appreciate if everyone would use this link instead: https://deeplearning4jblob.blob.core.windows.net/resources/wordvectors/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz

Comment: @CrabMan We get bills of a few thousands a month hosting that file and it ate up all of our AWS credits.

Comment: The link is broken

Answer (score 4):

Here is what worked for me. I loaded a part of the model and not the entire model as it's huge.

```
!pip install wget

import wget
url = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/dl4j-distribution/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz'
filename = wget.download(url)

f_in = gzip.open('GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz', 'rb')
f_out = open('GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin', 'wb')
f_out.writelines(f_in)

import gensim
from gensim.models import Word2Vec, KeyedVectors
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin', binary=True, limit=100000)
```

Comment: I'm trying to use your method but when I do the `wget.download(url)` I get `URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed>` any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this URL that points to Google Drive's download of the bin.gz file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7XkCwpI5KDYNlNUTTlSS21pQmM/edit?resourcekey=0-wjGZdNAUop6WykTtMip30g

Alternative mirrors (including the S3 mentioned here) seem to be broken.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33498105)

Answer (score 1):

Also available from **figshare**:

`wget https://figshare.com/ndownloader/files/10798046 -O GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin`